# Setting repeats in UnTimeIntervialNotification crashes the app.

Tags: ios, swift

so i am setting a local notification for my app, but whenever i set the repeats parameter to true, the app crashes.

```
UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true)
```

[image]

Comment: try increasing the time interval to at least 60

Comment: @Aakash i see.. thanks. Btw, do you know how to increase the length of the notification sound? For example, right now it is only a "beep" sound, can i make it a long buzzing sound? Thanks.

Comment: You just need to set the notification sound but the duration of the sound must not be more than 30 seconds